# Spring AOP: pointcut @annotation(MyAnnotation) && call(..) is not triggered as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to execute a set code in my advice but can't able to weave the code inside the function which has the `@SecuredAPI` annotation and calls the
`setQuery()` function.

Previously I tried the following pointcut and it worked very well

```java
call(* org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder.setQuery(org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder)) && args(queryBuilder)
```

But need to also include the annotated condition in this. Please help me with that.

My poincut and advice looks like this

```java
@Around(value = "@annotation(SecuredAPI)  && call(* org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder.setQuery(org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder)) && args(queryBuilder)" )
public Object decorateQuery(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, QueryBuilder queryBuilder) throws Throwable {
  // ...
}
```

And my function looks like this

```
@SecuredAPI
public List<Integer> getAllIds() {
  // ...
  SearchResponse response = conn
    .getESClient().prepareSearch(ElasticSearchConstants.ATTRIBUTE_INDEX)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
    //.setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(searchQuery))
    .setQuery(qb)
    .setFrom(0).setSize(10000).setExplain(true).get();
}
```

Please help me to find a way to may it work for following condition

Comment: Are you using Spring AOP or full AspectJ via LTW configuration? This makes a difference if you want to use a `call()` pointcut, thus my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, while editing your question (the code formatting was a bit chaotic) I read it again and you said that `call()` actually works for you. So you are not using Spring AOP because `call()` is not supported there. You must be using AspectJ, probably via LTW (load-time weaving) or maybe via CTW (compile-time weaving). It does not make a difference for the answer.

The problem is that `@annotation(SecuredAPI)` would actually work inside an `execution()` pointcut defined on your annotated method, but the method you call from there is not annotated, so the advice does not get triggered for `call()`. It only would if the target method `setQuery(..)` was annotated, but it is not. Consequently, `@annotation()` is not the right pointcut for your purpose.

What you want to express is: "a call to `setQuery(..)` from within code annotated by `@SecuredAPI`". This is done as follows (AspectJ example without Spring, please adjust class and package names to your needs):

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, FIELD, METHOD })
public @interface SecuredAPI {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething();
    application.doSomethingElse();
  }

  @SecuredAPI
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something before setting query");
    setQuery("my first query");
    System.out.println("Doing something after setting query");
  }

  public void doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("Doing something else before setting query");
    setQuery("my second query");
    System.out.println("Doing something else after setting query");
  }

  public void setQuery(String query) {
    System.out.println("Setting query to: " + query);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class SecuredAPIAspect {
  @Around("@withincode(de.scrum_master.app.SecuredAPI) && call(* setQuery(..))")
  public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

See? `@withincode()` is your friend in this case. The console log looks as follows:

```
Doing something before setting query
call(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.setQuery(String))
Setting query to: my first query
Doing something after setting query
Doing something else before setting query
Setting query to: my second query
Doing something else after setting query
```

Besides, you also need to use a fully-qualified class name for the annotation such as `de.scrum_master.app.SecuredAPI`, not just `SecuredAPI`, unless the annotation happens to be in the same package as your aspect.

Comment: thanks for your time and you answer really simplified the approach. I was using a more complex way of poincut to obtain the result.
*@Around("cflow(call(* org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder.setQuery(org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder))) && !within(AuthorizationAop) && args(queryBuilder) && !cflow(@annotation(biz.neustar.oneid.dc.authorization.DisableRestriction))")*